# connect between Grid View and List Veiw in kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, kotlin

I wonder if somebody can help me to solve this error bag "unfortunately, startup has stopped"
I did 3 activities and i wanna to connect between them by "setOnClickListener",
first activity for Grid View,
second for List View,
third for Details,
note: my application name is startup

**Here is a MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var adapter:FoodAdapter?=null
var listOfFoods =ArrayList<Food>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // load foods
     listOfFoods.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.a))
      ..........
    adapter= FoodAdapter(this,listOfFoods)

    gvListFood.adapter =adapter

}


class  FoodAdapter:BaseAdapter {
    var listOfFood= ArrayList<Food>()
    var context:Context?=null
    constructor(context:Context,listOfFood:ArrayList<Food>):super(){
        this.context=context
        this.listOfFood=listOfFood
    }
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val food = this.listOfFood[p0]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var foodView= inflator.inflate(R.layout.food_ticket,null)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setImageResource(food.image!!)
        foodView.ivFoodImage.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(context, Main2Activity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", food.name!!)
            intent.putExtra("des", food.des!!)
            intent.putExtra("image", food.image!!)

            context!!.startActivity(intent)
        }
        return foodView
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFood[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
       return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return listOfFood.size
    }

 }
}
```

**Here is a Main2Activity.kt**

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {
var adapter: FoodAdapter? = null
var listOfFoods2 = ArrayList<Food>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    val bundle= intent.extras
    val name = bundle.getString("name")
    val des = bundle.getString("des")
    val image = bundle.getInt("image")
    ivFoodImage2?.let{
        it.setImageResource(image)
    }
    //ivFoodImage2.setImageResource(image)
    tvName2?.let{
        it.text=name
    }
    //tvName2.text=name
    tvDes2?.let{
        it.text=des
    }
    //tvDes2.text=des




    // load foods


    listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.e))
    listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.f))
    listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.g))
    listOfFoods2.add(Food("Coffee","   Coffee preparation is",R.drawable.h))

    adapter = FoodAdapter(listOfFoods2, this)
    lvFoods2.adapter = adapter

}


 class FoodAdapter : BaseAdapter {
    var context: Context? = null
    var listOfFoodsLocal2 = ArrayList<Food>()

    constructor(listOfFoods2: ArrayList<Food>, context: Context) : super() {
        this.listOfFoodsLocal2 = listOfFoods2
        this.context = context
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val food = this.listOfFoodsLocal2[p0]
        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val foodView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.food_ticket2, null)
        foodView.tvName2?.let{

            it.text = food.name!!
        }
        //foodView.tvName2.text = food.name!!
        foodView.tvDes2?.let{

            it.text = food.des!!
        }
        //foodView.tvDes2.text = food.des!!
        foodView.ivFoodImage2?.let{

            it.setImageResource(food.image!!)
        }
        //foodView.ivFoodImage2.setImageResource(food.image!!)
        foodView.ivFoodImage2.setOnClickListener {

            //move to next
            val intent = Intent(context, FoodDetails::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("name", food.name!!)
            intent.putExtra("des", food.des!!)
            intent.putExtra("image", food.image!!)

            context!!.startActivity(intent)

        }
        return foodView

    }


    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return listOfFoodsLocal2[p0]
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return listOfFoodsLocal2.size
    }

}
```

}

**Here is a FoodDetails.kt**

```
class FoodDetails : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_details)
    val bundle= intent.extras
    val name = bundle.getString("name")
    val des = bundle.getString("des")
    val image = bundle.getInt("image")
    ivFoodImage3.setImageResource(image)
    tvName3.text=name
    tvDetails3.text=des
}
}
```

**Here is a Food.kt (for 3 objects)**

```
package com.marzadmz.startup

class  Food {
var name:String? =null
var des:String? =null
var image:Int? =null
constructor(name:String,des:String,image:Int){
    this.name=name
    this.des=des
    this.image=image
}
}
```

**Here is my Logcat**

```
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeec39450, tid 5472
09-09 14:16:11.338 5453-5472/com.marzadmz.startup I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-09 14:16:11.413 5453-5472/com.marzadmz.startup D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-09 14:16:11.448 5453-5472/com.marzadmz.startup W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-09 14:16:11.449 5453-5472/com.marzadmz.startup W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeec35780, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-09 14:16:11.557 5453-5468/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 92(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 18MB/18MB, paused 25.260ms total 52.920ms
09-09 14:16:11.590 5453-5468/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 46(1952B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 18MB/30MB, paused 14.620ms total 31.382ms
09-09 14:16:11.686 5453-5468/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 43(1408B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 72MB/72MB, paused 28.910ms total 31.763ms
09-09 14:16:11.965 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/Choreographer: Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-09 14:16:53.756 5453-5472/com.marzadmz.startup W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-09 14:16:53.756 5453-5472/com.marzadmz.startup W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3f5baa0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-09 14:16:53.793 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 209(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 72MB/88MB, paused 560us total 7.402ms
09-09 14:16:53.804 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 214(29KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 72MB/88MB, paused 1.062ms total 10.928ms
09-09 14:16:53.804 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 122MB allocation
09-09 14:16:53.814 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9(248B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 72MB/88MB, paused 541us total 9.879ms
09-09 14:16:53.815 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 128043252 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 23MB until OOM"
09-09 14:16:53.825 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(240B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 72MB/88MB, paused 807us total 6.145ms
09-09 14:16:53.834 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4(144B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 72MB/88MB, paused 1.097ms total 9.388ms
09-09 14:16:53.834 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 122MB allocation
09-09 14:16:53.844 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 72MB/88MB, paused 437us total 9.054ms
09-09 14:16:53.844 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 128043252 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 23MB until OOM"
09-09 14:16:53.844 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
09-09 14:16:53.844 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-09 14:16:53.845 5453-5453/com.marzadmz.startup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.marzadmz.startup, PID: 5453
                                                                java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 128043252 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 23MB until OOM
                                                                    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
                                                                    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:30)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:372)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:54)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:66)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                    at com.marzadmz.startup.Main2Activity$FoodAdapter.getView(Main2Activity.kt:69)
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(Linea
```

Comment: Please provide full log cat in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the LogCat we can conclude that in your `MainActivity2` in `Adapter` class

```
 foodView.ivFoodImage2.setImageResource(food.image!!)
```

the `ImageView` is null.

To add a safe check

```
    foodView.ivFoodImage2?.let{

  it.setImageResource(food.image!!)    
}
```

[image: thank you mzeus.bolt for your answer, I did it but its show me the same bag]

Looking at error the error is with the `ImageView` you are using in `onCreate` method on `MainActivity2` i.e; below given line:

```
ivFoodImage2.setImageResource(image)
```

Please make the same check with this as `ImageView` is `null`, It will be like:

```
ivFoodImage2?.let{
  it.setImageResource(image)
}
```

Comment: Thank you mzeus.bolt, please can you check my picture because its show me the same  error bag

Comment: I'm Trying to debug and i found this message inside "Main2Activity" class, please check my Logcat is updated
the massage is:
Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern 
More info:
[http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder]

Comment: Its the completely different error which you posted earlier. Its the Out Of Memory Error. You need to scale your image

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug and set break points. Perhaps you forget to initial something. Also please provide full log cat in your question.